# Need some help writing an if statement in UNIX bash scripting

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, grep, sh

I'm writing a reasonably lengthy script (or what I would consider lengthy - you could probably do it in a few hours). I basically have a file (named .restore.info) which contains files of names. In part of the script, I want to test "If cannot find filename in .restore.info, then says “Error: restored file does not exist”. Apologies if this doesn't make sense for you guys (for me, it does in the grand scheme of things). So if type this in the command line:

```
sh MYSCRIPT filename
```

It will search for the string filename in the .restore.info file, and if it cant find anything, it should produce an error message.

Basically, I need the top line of this coded translated into a UNIX bash statement and something that actually makes sense!:

```
If grep $1 .restore.info returns an exist status of 1; then
  echo “Filename does not exist!”
fi
```

Thanks in advance! Please ask me if you need me to clarify anything  more clearly as I know I'm not the best explainer, and I'll get back to you in less than a minute! (+rep and best answer of course will be given!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably only care if `grep` exits with a non-zero exit status:

```
if ! grep -q "$1" .restore.info; then
    echo "Filename does not exist!"
fi
```

but if you really do care about a specific exit status (1, in this case):

```
if ! grep -q "$1" .restore.info && [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Filename does not exist!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -q`

```
grep -q "filename" .restore.info && echo "found match"
```

or

```
! grep -q "filename" .restore.info && echo "not found"
```

Comment: You don't want to put `grep` inside `$()`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l 'filename' .restore.info
if [ $? = 0 ];then
   echo "found it"
else 
  echo "not found"
fi
```